# Input data in one line to array of bool

Tags: c++, cin

It's possible to type data in correct way to array of bool in one line?
I have something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  unsigned short a;
  cin >> a;

  bool *b = new bool[a];

  for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    cin >> b[i]; 

  for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    cout << b[i]; 

  delete [] b;

  return 0;
}
```

For example:

Correct input:

```
5
1
0
1
0
1
```

Correct output:

```
10101
```

But I want in this way:

Input:

```
5
10101
```

Output:

```
10101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read characters from input and convert them to bool, like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    b[i] = static_cast<bool>(c - '0');
}
```

Note: this will allow to enter both in single line and multiple ones, as cin ignore whitespace characters.

Comment: char is in fact 8 (on most architectures) bit integer of the value equivalent to ASCII value of character it holds. The operation subtract ASCII value of character '0' (48) from ASCII value of character c, so '0' becomes 0, and '1' becomes 1. Then it can be cast to bool, as integer 0 equals false and 1 equals true.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole input into a string and then convert '1' and '0' `char`s into `bool`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    std::cout << "Input length was: " << input.length() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Output: ";

    for (auto c : input)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<bool>(c - '0');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]